# How can I configure Firefox so that it doesn't leave an icon in the task bar upon exit in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, taskbar

Upon exit, Firefox leaves an icon in the task bar in Windows 10:

[image]

How can I configure Firefox so that it doesn't leave an icon in the task bar upon exit in Windows 10?

---

I tried right-clicking on the Firefox icon on the taskbar but there's no "Unpin from Taskbar" option:

[image]

I couldn't find any setting in Firefox to configure the exit:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Firefox was closed (and properly), right click on the Firefox icon on the taskbar and select "Unpin from Taskbar"  .

This works Windows 10 and 11 for any icon that can be removed (any closed app) .

Once unpinned, Firefox should no longer stay on the taskbar at Firefox exit. Make sure you have exited from Firefox.

**Note:** If there is no "Unpin from Taskbar" see if there is a "Pin to Taskbar" indicating that Firefox is not truly closed.

Check Firefox itself for Icon behavior in Firefox settings to see if there is an icon setting there. There may not be.

This all works and assumes everything in your system is working correctly.

If your system is not working correctly and if the Pin / Unpin options are not there, you may need to Repair Windows 10.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

and use the option to keep everything.

Double check afterward that all is well or possibly that Firefox has an issue.

Comment: Thanks, good idea, I tried right-clicking on the Firefox icon on the taskbar but there's no "Unpin from Taskbar" option: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6F7Z.png

Comment: That would only happen if Firefox is not truly closed (non closed apps stay on the taskbar) or there is a Setting in Firefox for Windows.  Outlook has that kind of setting

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any setting in Firefox yet.

Comment: I look in Firefox (Ubuntu and no setting there either) so it is managed in Windows.

Comment: If there is no "Unpin from Taskbar" see if there is a "Pin to Taskbar" indicating that Firefox is not truly closed.

Comment: Thanks, there's no pinning option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6F7Z.png

Comment: You may have to repair your machine because it looks now like a Windows  issue.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10   and Keep Everything.

Answer (score 0):

One can use this [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) script from [thewindowsclub.com](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/unpin-all-taskbar-icons-at-once-in-windows) to remove all pins:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*"
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband /F
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer
```

That worked to get rid of the two Firefox pins. No clue why only Firefox has this issue with Windows.